# pg_dump backup compression

Tags: backup, postgresql

When executing a pg_dump which should I use and why?

`pg_dump -U <user> <database> | gzip -c > backup.gz`

or

`pg_dump -F c -f backup.tar.gz -U <user> <database>`

Comment: In any case, don't use the `-d` option because it's deprecated since 8.4 and it has never meant to select the database to dump, it meant this instead (from [PG-8.3 doc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/app-pgdump.html)): > -d
> --inserts Dump data as INSERT commands (rather than COPY). This will make restoration very slow; it is mainly useful for making dumps that
> can be loaded into non-PostgreSQL databases. Also, it's not a good idea to suffix the filename of a dump in custom format (`-Fc`) with .tar.gz because it's **not** a gzipped tarfile. The custom dumps can only be processed

Answer (score 27, accepted):

According to the [`pg_dump` documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgdump.html) the custom format is:

> the most flexible output format in that it allows manual selection and
>   reordering of archived items during restore. This format is also
>   compressed by default

You can also select the compression level with the `-Z` option.

For simplicity I would definitely go for `pg_dump -F c` over piping to gzip.

Comment: I have a very small database now that is dumped with `-Fc`. It's only about 30k but running gzip on it compresses down to 20k. Not sure if that's overhead that would be insignificant in a larger database.